# How to use PJ_SIP of asterisk with pjsip library

Tags: ios, asterisk, voip, pjsip

Will pjsip library (www.pjsip.org) support PJ_SIP of asterisk? 
I checked with CHAN_SIP is working fine, but we are not able to register with PJ_SIP account. Do we need to change any configuration or need to add any extra parameter at the time of registration to make it working with pjsip Library specially for mobile support?

Answer (score 0):

pjsip library will support any sip-compliant switch.

Yes, including asterisk.

Yes, you have understand sip, nat traversal, nat issues etc etc etc.